# Nodejs function returns before internal function completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am trying to return whether a user already exists in a MongoDB. Running `console.log` within `collection.find()` prints the correct amount (greater than 0). However, when `userExists` is called, it always returns `false` (0).

How do I make Javascript wait for these functions to complete before returning a value? I've read about jQuery's `$.Deffered()`, but this feels dirty to me, and it didn't work.

```
function userExists(db, uid){
    var collection = db.get('users');
    var ret = 0;

    collection.find({"uid":uid},{},function(e,docs){
        ret = docs.length
    });

    return ret > 0?true:false;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some have noted, `collection.find` is asynchronous, so when you reach the next line in `userExists` (the line where you've got `return ret > 0?true:false;`), it's too early and the value of `ret` hasn't been set. Anywhere outside of the callback to `collection.find` (and any functions it calls in turn), the query hasn't happened yet.

There is (basically) no way to "pause" `userExists` until after the query, so you need to change your whole approach. What you need is the **Continuation Pattern.** This means that whatever you're doing with the result of `collection.find` has to happen in the callback.

I don't know what you're trying to do with `ret`, so this might mean big changes to how your code is organized. Here's an outline that I hope will give you the general idea:

```
function processResultAndDisplayToTheUser(ret) {
    //everything that needs to happen after the value of ret is set
    if (ret > 0) {
       doSomething();
    } else {
       doSomethingElse();
    }
}

function userExists(db, uid){
    var collection = db.get('users');

    //ret doesn't exist here

    collection.find({"uid":uid}, {}, function(e,docs){
        var ret = docs.length;

        //ret finally exists, so pass it to a function and use it
        processResultAndDisplayToTheUser(ret);
    });

    //ret doesn't exist here either
}

//ret still doesn't exist here
```

Comment: I took the hint from so many posts about asynchronous functions and restructured my code. Will post in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

I took the hint and ended up restructuring my code. I created a function addUpdateUser(), did the count there, then ran the addUser() or updateUser() functions accordingly.

```
addUpdateUser(db, {
    "uid" : uid,
}); 

function addUpdateUser(db, userInfo){
    var collection = db.get('users');

    collection.find({"uid":userInfo.uid},{},function(e,docs){
        if(docs.length > 0){
            updateUser(db, userInfo)
        }else{
            addUser(db, userInfo)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why're you using `ret` at all here? Seems redundant to the design.

Answer (score 0):

since collection.find is asynchronous method that doesn't return immediately you need to change your code to,

you can pass a callback function

```
 function userExists(db, uid,callback){
var collection = db.get('users');


   collection.find({"uid":uid},{},function(e,docs){

    callback(docs.length);
   });

 }
```

now you can call this userExists function as

```
      userExists(db, uid,function(ret){
                              //do something here

              })
```

Comment: See the other answer, you've made the same mistake. That will not work.

Comment: Ok, that would work now. You can also get rid of the `ret` variable by just passing `docs.length` to the call to `callback`.

Comment: This is that kind of structure I keep seeing everywhere. Is callback() a real JavaScript function? Does callback somehow get routed to ret when userExists is called? Sorry for my inability to wrap my brain around this.

Comment: In your answer, ret never actually exists til you call userExists(). Where does it come from?

Comment: actually @HallHelton, not you are passing docs.length to callback function, which you can say anything i wrote it "ret" for your understanding

Comment: I used the above for another section of my code. I'm blown away. This is very useful. To answer my earlier question, callback is a function.

Comment: yes callback is a function, you can pass directly or can declare some where else and pass name as parameter